# Requirejs don't load data-main

Tags: javascript, requirejs

hello i have such html

```
<body>
 ...
 <div id="game">
   console
   <div id="message"></div>
   <script data-main="js/console" src="/js/lib/require.js"></script>
 </div>
...
</body>
```

And my js/console.js doesn't load( i see this in chrome dev tools), any ideas?
console.js

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "_=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        jquery: "/js/lib/jquery",
        underscore: "/js/lib/underscore",
        backbone: "/js/lib/backbone",
        Connector: "/js/lib/Connector",
        FnQuery: "/js/lib/FnQuery",
        "socket.io": "/socket.io/socket.io"
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        "socket.io": {
            exports: "io"
        }
    }
});

define([
    'Connector'
], function(
    Connector
){...
});
```

as i undestand the problem is, that i insert this div() using teplates and it doesn't load js, is it possible to load it using jquery or smth else?

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
   <script data-main="./js/console" src="/js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide explanation, if that's possible.

Comment: as i undestand the problem is, that i insert this div(`<div id="game">`) using teplates and it doesn't load js, is it possible to load it using jquery or smth else?